# Lock down binding to WCF service

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service that is used as a data proxy for a Windows Forms client. I would like to secure the Windows Forms / WCF Service binding in such a way that ONLY the Windows Forms client can bind to the service. I don't want the windows users to be able to bind to the service in other ways such as powershell, C#, etc.

The WCF client instance used by the Forms app is using https to bind to WCF which is hosted on IIS. The Forms app also uses default Windows credentials to bind to the WCF service. I'm using basichttpbinding. Everything there works great.

I was thinking of using a certificate with a private key where the client would need the matching private key of the certificate embedded in the service. At what level would you implement that, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There just so happens to be [a huge nine-step tutorial over on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx) for certificate authentication in WCF from a Windows Form client.

Comment: Hm, yes I think this is what I was looking for. I will give it a shot, I have not configured "Message Security" within the client and wcf service to use a certificate for its binding. Thanks Cory, I'll let you know how it turns out after I work through the MSDN article.